# Using "Kubegres" Postgres Operator for Kubernetes, how can database name be set?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-operator

Using the Postgres operator for Kubernetes "Kubegres" (https://www.kubegres.io),
how can the name of the database be set? By default the operator creates a database with name "postgres".

I am referring to the Postgres database name here passed by flag `-d`, a.k.a. `dbname`:

```
psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d postgres -U postgres -W
```

not the name of the Kubernetes service "mypostgres", shown in this sample manifest from https://www.kubegres.io/doc/getting-started.html:

```
apiVersion: kubegres.reactive-tech.io/v1
kind: Kubegres
metadata:
  name: mypostgres
  namespace: default

spec:

   replicas: 2
   image: postgres:14.1


   database:
      size: 200Mi

   env:
      - name: POSTGRES_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:
              name: mypostgres-secret
              key: superUserPassword

      - name: POSTGRES_REPLICATION_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
           secretKeyRef:
              name: mypostgres-secret
              key: replicationUserPassword
```

It does not appear to be in these properties
https://www.kubegres.io/doc/properties-explained.html

I do not think this works:

```
   env:
      - name: POSTGRES_DB
        value: keycloak
```

It does not change the dbname:

```
$ psql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -d keycloak -U postgres -W
Password: 
psql: error: FATAL:  database "keycloak" does not exist
```

Thank you

Comment: It looks like that is answered [here](https://www.kubegres.io/doc/override-default-configs.html). Or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You're absolutely right, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Override primary_init_script.sh

https://www.kubegres.io/doc/override-default-configs.html